# Display current category name in breadcrumbs (using angularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breadcrumbs

I'm struggling to make my category and vendor name visible on breadcrumbs. 
I'm using ng-breadcrumbs module (https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs).

I guess I have problem with making curCategory and curVendor globally acessible, but tried some ways and can't make it working.

Here is my html:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as main">
(...)
<ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get({'Category':curCategory,'Vendor': curVendor}) track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }">
  <a ng-if="!$last" ng-href="#{{ breadcrumb.path }}" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label" class="margin-right-xs"></a>
  <span ng-if="$last" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label"></span>
 </li>
</ol>
```

My routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/pages/main.html',
        label: 'Home'
      }).
      when('/:cat', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/pages/category.html',
        label: 'Category'
      }).
      when('/:cat/:ven', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/pages/vendor.html',
        label: 'Vendor'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

My controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [
  'ngRoute', 
  'ng-breadcrumbs'
]);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $routeParams, breadcrumbs) {

  $scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;

  $scope.curCategory = $routeParams.cat;
  $scope.curVendor = $routeParams.ven;

  (...)

});
```

Comment: This looks actaully fine ... could you reproduce your bug in a plunker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff I found what was wrong!

What suprised me was that inside specific controllers it worked fine, but when I moved it to mainController it returned empty object from $routeParams.

Here is solution:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  $scope.curCategory = $routeParams.cat;
  $scope.curVendor = $routeParams.ven;
});
```

It just assigned variables before $routeParams were populated.